# is there another way to create an image gallery using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a online e-commerce website and I'm stuck trying to resolve a TypeError message that seems to be caused by the code I wrote for an image gallery on the product detail page on my website(I created a separate html page for it, if that's relevant).
My image gallery consists of 4 images in total; 1 main image(large) and three smaller ones.
The desired output is to have the main image .src to change to one of the smaller image's .src depending which of the smaller images was clicked on.. Hope that makes sense.

So I wrote some code that does what I need it to, however the TypeError message gets displayed every time the page is loaded and it prevents other code from working.
So if anyone is able to assist me, that would be great. I've attached code snippets bellow, Thanks!

HTML

```
<section id="Product-details">
      <div class="single-pro-img">
        <img src="images/image75.jpg" width="100%" id="main-img" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail  mx-4"  alt="">
        <div class="smallImg-group">
          <div class="small_img-col">
            <img src="images/image80.jpg" width="100%" class="small-img img-fluid img-thumbnail mx-4">
          </div>
          <div class="small_img-col">
            <img src="images/image72.jpg" width="100%" class="small-img img-fluid img-thumbnail mx-4">
          </div>
          <div class="small_img-col">
            <img src="images/image77.jpg" width="100%" class="small-img img-fluid img-thumbnail mx-4">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="singlePro-details">
        <h6>store/Lace set</h6>
        <h4>The Lace Collection</h4>
        <h2><b>ZAR</b>450.99</h2>
        <select>
          <option>Select size</option>
          <option>xs</option>
          <option>s</option>
          <option>M</option>
          <option>L</option>
          <option>XL</option>
        </select>
        <input type="number" value="1">
        <button class="btn1">Add To Cart</button>
        <h4>Product Details</h4>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Nulla dolorem voluptas cumque ipsa iste inventore consequuntur aut similique, dolores ut eum exercitationem suscipit enim fugiat facilis velit soluta reprehenderit excepturi maiores ipsam dolore? 
          Aliquid accusantium dolor ipsam voluptas similique.
          Iusto voluptatem dolor perferendis, est molestias porro magni explicabo qui amet.</span>
      </div>
    </section>
```

JavaScript

```
let mainImg = document.getElementById("main-img");
let smallimg = document.getElementsByClassName("small-img");

 smallimg[0].onclick = function(){
    mainImg.src = smallimg[0].src;
 }
 smallimg[1].onclick = function(){
    mainImg.src = smallimg[1].src;
 }
 smallimg[2].onclick = function(){
    mainImg.src = smallimg[2].src;
 }
```

The following is the error message that keeps popping up:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'onclick')
at script.js:20:22
(anonymous) @ script.js:20

Comment: Your code works. How are you calling your script? Is it in the header, or just before the `</body>` tag? If it's in the header [are you deferring it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer)?

Comment: The initialization of the gallery behavior can not be executed/triggered before the [DOM content has been entirely loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event). Thus any script which needs full DOM access has to be included last into the document's body. As a side note ... There is still quite some room for the markup's semantic improvement.

Comment: @Andy, My code is just before the closing body tag. it is placed before the other script tags that I used for frameworks such as Bootstrap and so forth.